# How to get list of all the renderings that has been configured to use data source

Tags: powershell-extensions

We are almost complete with a large project.

I am trying to find out which rendering in the page has been configured to use data source using a Powershell script. So that we can run in both UAT and Prod to make sure all rendering data source has been configured properly.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question with what you've tried or thought about so far?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on your question I think you need something that will require a bit more finesse, so here's my attempt - It will only show renderings that have no datasource, but need them

```powershell
function Test-DataSourceRequired {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([Sitecore.Data.ID]$RenderingId)

    $rendering = Get-Item master: -ID $RenderingId

    # if data source location and data source template are empty then it's ok for the rendering to have no data source defined
    return -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($rendering."Datasource Location") -or -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($rendering."Datasource Template")
}

function Test-ContainRenderingsWithoutDataSources  {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [Sitecore.Data.Items.Item]$Item)

    #Test Versioned Layout
    $BrokenRendering = Get-Rendering -Item $Item -FinalLayout | Where-Object { ($_.Datasource -eq "") -and (Test-DataSourceRequired $_.ItemID) }
    $BrokenRendering | %{ Write-Host "$($Item.Paths.Path) - '$((Get-Item master: -ID $_.ItemId).Name)' has no datasource" -ForegroundColor Red } 

}

Get-Item -Path master:\content\Home | Test-ContainRenderingsWithoutDataSources
```

In this case I'm checking whether the rendering that we are inspecting (that has no datasource specified) actually requires one. By requires I understand that the rendering has a value in "DataSource Location" and "DataSource Template". that filters out false positives where renderings that don't need datasource would be shown.

You can pipe multiple items into the cmdlet as well like:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Path master:\content\Home -Recurse | Test-ContainRenderingsWithoutDataSources
```

Sample output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution would be to inspect the renderings of every item and print out the ID of an item and the value of the Datasource:

```
Get-ChildItem /sitecore/content/home -Recurse | Get-Rendering |? { $_.Datasource -ne "" } | ft OwnerItemId, Datasource
```

You can further work on the `Format-Table` (ft) syntax to get more appealing result.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `DataSource` parameter together with a Wildcard filter to only select renderings that have a Datasource:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Get-Rendering -Datasource "*"
```

Remember that, in Sitecore 8 onwards, this will target the Shared Layout. If you want to get the Final Layout you should also specify the `-FinalLayout` parameter.